# How to convert 01:30 pm to 13:30:00 in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I used MYSQL TIME() function to change the time format. But it gives only the time, not recognize the am or pm.

I got 01:30:00 from TIME('01:30 pm'). I want to achieve it only in MYSQL. No PHP or others. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not a real time you are storing in mysql since you also have am/pm

You first need to convert to real `datetime` using `str_to_date` and then use `time_format`

```
mysql> select time_format(str_to_date('01:30 pm','%h:%i %p'),'%H:%i:%s') as time ;
+----------+
| time     |
+----------+
| 13:30:00 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you. It is working in higher version. But not working in lower version. Lower version returns NULL. Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use  this function [TIME_FORMAT(time,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)